# Can I map an internal IP address to a domain name, when on a particular network?

Tags: networking, dns, ip, vpn, hosts

I have a server at home, with internal IP `192.168.1.100`. I use a dynamic DNS service so that I can reach it at `http://foo.dynu.com` when I am out. When I have my laptop at home, I know that I could directly connect to the server by adding the following line to `/etc/hosts`.

```
192.168.1.100    foo.dynu.com
```

However, is there a way to automatically apply this redirect *only* when I'm on my home network? (I usually connect via a particular wifi connection, although I occasionally connect via ethernet. If this complicates matters, then I'm happy to only set it for the wifi connection.) I use Network Manager.

Also, I connect to the internet via a VPN, so presumably any configuration on my (OpenWRT) router is unlikely to work.

Comment: You could possibly add a Network Manager Dispatcher hook that adds an entry to `/etc/hosts` when a particular interface (your VPN) comes up.

Comment: @garethTheRed That seems like a reasonable solution (although it'd depend on location for my usage, not VPN). Let me chase that up and I'll get back to you.

Comment: @garethTheRed Thanks! That worked well. I posted up a solution, but really, the original answer came from you. If you post one up, I'm happy to delete mine, then edit and accept your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per @garethTheRed's suggestion in the comments, I created a Network Manager Dispatcher hook.

Create the following file at `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/99_foo.dynu.com.sh`. This progresses when a new network connection is detected (i.e. ethernet or wifi). It then identifies my "home network" in two ways: the BSSID/SSID and the static IP that my router assigns me. (At the moment it doesn't work when I connect via ethernet, since that's relatively rare.) It then appends the mapping to the hosts file if we are in the home network; if not, then it removes this line.

```
#!/bin/sh
# Map domain name to internal IP when connected to home network (via wifi)
# Partially inspired by http://sysadminsjourney.com/content/2008/12/18/use-networkmanager-launch-scripts-based-network-location/

WIFI_ID_TEST='Connected to 11:11:11:11:11:11 (on wlp3s0)
    SSID: WifiName'
LOCAL_IP_TEST='192.168.1.90'
MAPPING='192.168.1.100    foo.dynu.com'
HOSTS_PATH=/etc/hosts

IF=$1
STATUS=$2
# Either wifi or ethernet goes up
if [ "$STATUS" = 'up' ] && { [ "$IF" = 'wlp3s0' ] || [ "$IF" = 'enp10s0' ]; }; then
  # BSSID and my static IP, i.e. home network
  if [ "$(iw dev wlp3s0 link | head -n 2)" = "$WIFI_ID_TEST" ] && [ -n "$(ip addr show wlp3s0 to ${LOCAL_IP_TEST})" ]; then
    grep -qx "$MAPPING" "$HOSTS_PATH" || echo "$MAPPING" >> "$HOSTS_PATH"
  else
    ESC_MAPPING="^$(<<<"$MAPPING" sed 's/\./\\./g')$"
    sed -i "/${ESC_MAPPING}/d" "$HOSTS_PATH"
  fi
fi
```